# Calculating a limit with a result that is discontinuous in the parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

The following limit is left unevaluated (*Edit:* added the assumption that $\epsilon$ is real thanks to the comment below):

```
Limit[ 1/(1 + Exp[ϵ/T]), T->0, Direction->-1, Assumptions->ϵ ∈ Reals]
```

However, the limit is easy to calculate (it is the [Fermi-Dirac distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi-Dirac_distribution)), and it gives $\theta(-\epsilon)$. It seems that MMA has a hard time when the result is discontinuous in the parameters.
Nevertheless, MMA can actually calculate the limit, if we help it by explicitly splitting up the parameter space:

```
In[2]:= Limit[1/(1 + Exp[ϵ/T]), T->0, Direction->-1, Assumptions->#] & /@ {ϵ > 0, ϵ < 0}
Out[2]= {0, 1}
```

**Is there a way to make MMA automatically calculate such limits, without explicitly splitting up the parameter space?**

Comment: The thing here is that *Mathematica* always thinks that variables take on complex values, unless told otherwise (via, say, `Assuming[]` or the `Assumptions` option)...

Comment: @J.M. - Good point, however trying to use the assumption `ϵ ∈ Reals` still leaves the limit unevaluated (I edited the question to add this).

Comment: Yes, that's why I only posted a comment as opposed to an answer. Note that both `HeavisideTheta[]` and `UnitStep[]` have a different definition from your $\theta(u)$; your limit evaluates to $\dfrac12$ for $\varepsilon=0$, for instance.

Comment: @J.M. - You are correct, I will be satisfied, for example, with a `Piecewise` function as a result. BTW, why did you remove the _limits_ tag from the question?

Comment: It's a bit too specific (that is, unless I see multiple `Limit[]`-related questions cropping up, I don't see the need); at the moment, [tag:calculus-and-analysis] is sufficient to cover your question.

Comment: As there is no Limit (only directionally, going from left or from right), Mma is not going to give you an answer. Equivalent to your construction `Limit[1/(1 + Exp[x/T]), T -> 0, Direction -> #, 
   Assumptions -> x > 0] & /@ {1, -1}`

Comment: @belisarius - Indeed in the example I gave in the question  the different assumptions are equivalent to different directions. However, how about this example: `1/(1 + Exp[ϵ/T]) + 1/(1 + Exp[(ϵ - 1)/T])`. Now there are different results for `ϵ<0`, `0<ϵ<1` and `1<ϵ`, and I don't see how your comment applies here.

Comment: @Joe I was only trying to say that if the limit from the right is different from the limit from the left, Mma will not give you a result

Comment: I believe there is no way to get `Limit` to do what you want here.