# Problem with limit that requires L'Hôpital's rule to compute

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, assumptions

Consider the following limit.

```
Limit[(a - Sqrt[a^2 + x])/(a^2 - a*Sqrt[a^2 - x]), x -> 0, Assumptions -> {a > 0}]
```

Mathematica 9.0.1.0 gives `-1/a`, which is the correct answer.
Notice that this limit is not trivial to compute, because both the numerator and denominator vanish when `x=0`.
Therefore, L'Hopital's rule is required here.

Now remove the assumption.

```
Limit[(a - Sqrt[a^2 + x])/(a^2 - a*Sqrt[a^2 - x]), x -> 0]
```

For this, Mathematica gives `1/a`, which is incorrect for general `a` (although it is correct for `a<0`).

Is this last result a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: By elementary algebra, the function is equivalent to `-((a + Sqrt[a^2 - x])/(a (a + Sqrt[a^2 + x])))`, so L'Hôpital's rule is not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 5):

This code should give you some insight as to why you are seeing this behavior:

```
Manipulate[Plot[(a - Sqrt[a^2 + x])/(a^2 - a*Sqrt[a^2 - x]), {x, -1, 1}], {a, -3, 3}]
```

When `Assumptions -> {a > 0}` is used, you get the correct limit.  But when no assumptions are placed, Mathematica tries to evaluate the limit for a general complex $a$.  This second result is not correct for $\Re(a) > 0$:  The correct limit is $-1/a$ for $\Re(a) > 0$, and $1/a$ for $\Re(a) < 0$.

In general, limits whose values depend discontinuously on some parameter can be difficult for Mathematica to evaluate properly:  see [Calculating a limit with a result that is discontinuous in the parameters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/calculating-a-limit-with-a-result-that-is-discontinuous-in-the-parameters?rq=1) for example.

Comment: If the result depends on the parameters, then shouldn't Mathematica refuse to evaluate without additional assumptions, and just return Limit[...]?